# How can I use np.where with different data types? Is there an alternative? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm working on a dataframe that has 2 possible ways of labeling canceled loans. I want to create a column with a calculated CHARGEOFF_DATE.

First, the account can be labeled 'Canceled' by the date found on df['ACCOUNT_CODE'].
Second, I want to include any loans that are 120+ days delinquent as charged off by shifting the date 121 from the df['LAST_PAYMENT_DATE']

I keep getting an error about data types while using nested np.where. I am confused because both 'True' statements that I am using in np.where are in datetime format.

Pseudocode: if ACCOUNT_CODE is equal to 'Canceled', then return ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE.
Else if DAYS_DELINQUENT is greater than 120, return LAST_PAYMENT_DATE + 121 days shifted forward.
Else, return BLANK (I tried np.nan and '')

Here is the code I have so far:

```
delta = dt.timedelta(days=121) #set delta

df['CHARGEOFF_DATE'] = np.where(df['ACCOUNT_CODE'] == 'Canceled',df['ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE'],(np.where(df['DAYS_DELINQUENT'] > 120,(df['LAST_PAYMENT_DATE']+delta),np.nan)))
```

error I'm receiving:

```
 23 delta = dt.timedelta(days=121) #set delta
---> 24 df['CHARGEOFF_DATE'] = np.where(df['ACCOUNT_CODE'] == 'Canceled',df['ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE'],(np.where(df['DAYS_DELINQUENT'] > 120,(df['LAST_PAYMENT_DATE']+delta), '')))
     25 
     26 

<__array_function__ internals> in where(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[float16]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.
```

EDIT:
Here are the column data types
LAST_PAYMENT_DATE            datetime64[ns]
DAYS_DELINQUENT                       int64
ACCOUNT_CODE                         object
ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE            datetime64[ns]

Mock Dataset:
| LAST_PAYMENT_DATE| DAYS_DELINQUENT | ACCOUNT_CODE      |ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE|
| :----------------| :-------------- | :-----------      | :-------------- |
| 06/15/2020       | 0               | Paid in Full      | 06/15/2020      |
| 03/10/2021       | 362             | Legal Category    | 07/09/2021      |
| 10/03/2019       | 1186            | Canceled          | 01/15/2020      |
| 08/04/2021       | 150             | Legal Category    | 02/07/2021      |
| 09/02/2021       | 90              | Automatic Payment | 03/20/2019      |

I was able to land a solution by defining a function:

```
delta = dt.timedelta(days=121) #set days delta

def coFunc(row): #create a function that will test account code, else test days delinquent for greater than 120
    if row['ACCOUNT_CODE'] == 'Canceled':
        return row['ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE']
    elif row['DAYS_DELINQUENT'] > 120:
          return (row['LAST_PAYMENT_DATE']+delta)
    else:
        return ''
        
df['CHARGEOFF_DATE'] = df.apply(coFunc, axis=1)  #apply function to df
```

Comment: Can you create a mock dataset that generates this error?

Comment: If you print `df.dtypes`, what are the types of 'ACCOUNT_CODE_DATE' and 'LAST_PAYMENT_DATE'?  The implication is that one of them is a float.

Comment: `np.nan` is a `float`.  It cannot be put in the same array or `Series` with `numpy.dtype[datetime64]` values.